# PyQT5 как отобразить соответствующий список файлов при нажатии на Button_click

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, передача-параметров

Есть условно три раздела (`button 1`, `button 2`, `button 3`) при нажатии на одну из кнопок `button` должен открыться соответствующий ему список файлов в новом
окне.

Задача по идее сводится к передаче параметров соответствующих при `button_click.connect(...)`. Сам механизм добавления списка файлов работает, но вот как передать соответствующий параметр ? Как можно передать список_файлов_2 при нажатии другой кнопки button_2 из одного окна в другой теряюсь...

[image: окно разделов уроков]

[image: выбранный раздел уровков со списком файлов]

**Ссылка на соответствующий проект:**
[проект видеоуроки](https://github.com/almaz114/Video_uroki)

Comment: Расскажите пожалуйста подробнее о порядке действий, что и в какой последовательности нажимать и при нажатии чего вы хотите что-то (что именно) передать и куда надо передать (в какой объект/виджет).

Comment: В окне_1 (где расположены три раздела условно, button 1,2,3) нажав допустим на button_2.click должно открыться главное окно управления на котором размещены play,pause и тд. и виджет QlistView принимаюший на себя определенный список файлов playlist ; В этот playlist данные попадают с помошью функции open_spisok(self, path_new) при нажатии кнопки загрузить список файлов с передачей параметра path_new , в котором содержится путь к определенной папке ... но хотелось бы чтобы список заполнялся при нажатии на кнопку допустим Button в окне_1 с передачей параметра path_new, т.е из окна выбора разделов

Comment: То есть выбрав например раздел  № 2(нажимая button_2 передаем параметр путь _к_папке) в окне выбора разделов , откроется окно управления которое примет этот параметр для playlist, соответвенно загрузив при этом данные с учетом этого параметра! Нажимая другой Button_3 соответвенно загрузится playlist с параметром в Button_3

Comment: хорошо. я гляну

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из того что я понял, вам надо обратить внимание:

- изменения внесены ТОЛЬКО для действий по нажатию на кнопку (`pushButton_2 - "МОНТАЖ ЭЛЕКТРООБОРУДОВАНИЯ"`)
- на строки помеченные как `# !!!` или `# +++`
- на метод `closeEvent` главного окна, при закрытии главного окна -
  открываетс окно `функция вызова окна (Основной раздел)- метод show_window_1`,
  из которого можно закрыть приложение.

---

```
import sys
import os
import time
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

main_path = "D:\\Видео уроки\\"
path_1 = "D:\\Видео уроки\\1 Видео по сборке электробусов"               # путь к Раздел 1

# Установите свой путь vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv                          # !!! 
path_2 = "D:\\_Qt\\__Qt\\Test\Видео уроки\\Video_Player\\__pycache__\\"  # путь к Разделу 2   # !!! +++

path_3 = "C:\\Users\\Almaz\\PycharmProjects\\Video_Player\\movies"       # путь к Разделу 3

def hhmmss(ms):
    # s = 1000
    # m = 60000
    # h = 360000
    s = round(ms / 1000)
    m, s = divmod(s, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    return ("%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)) if h else ("%d:%02d" % (m, s))

class Window1(QWidget):                                               
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window1, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Раздел 1')
        self.setMinimumWidth(930)
        self.setMinimumHeight(450)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 531, 151))  
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 150))        
        self.label.move(225, 50)                                 
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText("ВЫБЕРИТЕ РАЗДЕЛ ВИДЕОУРОКОВ")
        self.label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 22))

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 211, 81))
        # self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #A3C1DA; color: green;}')
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.move(70, 190)
        self.pushButton.setText("СБОРКА АВТОБУСОВ")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 250, 81))  # 250 - ширина кнопки
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.move(330, 190)
        self.pushButton_2.setText("МОНТАЖ  \n ЭЛЕКТРООБОРУДОВАНИЯ")

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 250, 81))  # 250 - ширина кнопки
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3.move(630, 190)
        self.pushButton_3.setText("УСТАНОВКА ДВЕРНЫХ \n СИСТЕМ (CAMOZZI)")

class Window1_1(QWidget):  # Окно № 1   Раздел 1.1   Сборка автобусов
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window1_1, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Сборка автобусов')
        self.setMinimumWidth(930)
        self.setMinimumHeight(450)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 531, 151))
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 150))  
        self.label.move(255, 50)  
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText("ВЫБЕРИТЕ ПОДРАЗДЕЛЫ")
        self.label.setFont(QFont('Arial', 22))

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 245, 81))
        # self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {background-color: #A3C1DA; color: green;}')
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.move(70, 190)
        self.pushButton.setText("1.1 Монтаж тягового \n электрооборудования 6282")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 290, 81)) 
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_2.move(330, 190)
        self.pushButton_2.setText("1.2 Монтаж элементов  \n интерьера электробуса 6282")

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 250, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3.move(630, 190)
        self.pushButton_3.setText("1.3 Монтаж элементов \n экстерьера 6282")

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('show_window_2')
        self.button.show()

class Window2(QWidget):    # Окно № 2
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window2, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Window2')
        self.setMinimumWidth(270)
        self.setMinimumHeight(250)
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('Показать панель управления воспроизведением')
        self.button.show()


class ViewerWindow(QMainWindow):  # класс для работы с окном № 2
    # если state is True то по идее запускается окно № 2
    state = pyqtSignal(bool)  

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        # Emit the window state, to update the viewer toggle button.
        self.state.emit(False)  # класс для работы с окном № 2   


class PlaylistModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, playlist, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.playlist = playlist

    def data(self, index, role):  # получаем имя файла fileName
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            media = self.playlist.media(index.row())

            print(media.canonicalUrl().fileName())
            return media.canonicalUrl().fileName()

    def rowCount(self, index):  # получаем кол-во записей в playlist-e
        # print(self.playlist.mediaCount())
        return self.playlist.mediaCount()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):             # Главное окно программы
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.error.connect(self.erroralert)
        self.player.play()
        # Setup the playlist.
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)

        test = None  # ? -------

        # Add viewer for video playback, separate floating window.
        self.viewer = ViewerWindow(self)
        self.viewer.setWindowFlags(self.viewer.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.viewer.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 360))

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.viewer.setCentralWidget(videoWidget)# второе окно ко-е видео воспроизводит
        self.player.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)  # основное окно с кнопками

        # Connect control buttons/slides for media player.
        self.playButton.pressed.connect(self.player.play)  
        self.pauseButton.pressed.connect(self.player.pause)
        self.stopButton.pressed.connect(self.player.stop)
        self.volumeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setVolume)
        # кнопка при нажатии на ко-й откроется новое окно
        self.viewButton.toggled.connect(self.toggle_viewer)  
        # self.viewer.state.connect(self.viewButton.setChecked) # ??? где сама функция

        self.previousButton.pressed.connect(self.playlist.previous)
        self.nextButton.pressed.connect(self.playlist.next)
        self.model = PlaylistModel(self.playlist)
        self.playlistView.setModel(self.model)  # QListView - содержащий список файлов
        self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.playlist_position_changed)
        selection_model = self.playlistView.selectionModel()  # работа с листом списком видеофайлов
        selection_model.selectionChanged.connect(self.playlist_selection_changed)
        # selection_model.clear()
        self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.update_duration)
        self.player.positionChanged.connect(self.update_position)
        self.timeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setPosition)

        # self.open_file_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)
        # загрузка списка файлов при нажатии на Button в окне управления
        # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_spisok)  
        # -- загрузка списка файлов -- #
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(
            lambda ch, path_new=path_3: self.open_spisok(path_new)
        )   # откроем список файлов,  path_new - параметр
        # -- Очистка списка -- #
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clear_spisok)  

        # -- вовзрат в основной раздел -- #
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.hide)          
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.close_viewer)   
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.show_window_1)  
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)   # актвность drag & drop метода

    def show_window_1(self): # функция вызова окна (Основной раздел)
        self.w1 = Window1()
        self.w1.show()
        self.w1.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.show_Window1_1) # Открываем раздел 1
        self.w1.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.w1.hide)  # скрываем основной раздел
# !!! vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.w1.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.show_main_window('2'))     # Открываем раздел 2                        # !!! +++ 2
       # передаем условный номер раздела ->^                                                    # !!!
        self.w1.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.w1.hide)

        self.w1.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.show_main_window('3'))     
       # передаем условный номер раздела ->^ 
        self.w1.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.w1.hide)
# !!! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def show_main_window(self, section=0):  # функция вызова окна управления               #  +++ section
# !!!    
# ?        self.window = MainWindow()               # !!! ЭТОГО ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ НАДО
# ?       self.window.show()                        # !!! ЭТОГО ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ НАДО

         #print(f'section ---> {section}')
         if section == '2':                                                                #  +++ 
             self.open_spisok(path_2)                                                      #  +++ 
             # ------------>> ^^^^^^
         # ...

         self.show()                                                                       #  +++ 

    def show_Window1_1(self):
        print("откроем окно раздел 1_1")
        self.w1_1 = Window1_1()
        self.w1_1.show()

    def show_window_2(self):  # функция вызова второго окна
        self.w2 = Window2()
        self.w2.show()
        # при нажатии на Button показываем главное окно упрвления
        self.w2.button.clicked.connect(self.show_main_window)  

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasUrls():
            e.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, e):  
        for url in e.mimeData().urls():
            self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(url))
            print(" url :" + str(url))
            print("QMediaContent url :" + str(QMediaContent(url)))

        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

        # If not playing, seeking to first of newly added + play.
        if self.player.state() != QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            i = self.playlist.mediaCount() - len(e.mimeData().urls())
            self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(i)
            print("i :" + str(i))
            self.player.play()  

    def open_spisok(self, path_new):   # загрузки файлов в список mediaplayer
        #  path_new = "D:\\Видео_Инструкции\\Монтаж элементов интерьера электробуса 6282"
        self.playlist.clear()  # очишаем список
        print("очишаем список playlist перед заполнением")
        files = os.listdir(path_new)  # список имен файлов в папке path
        print("files: " + str(files))  # список файлов с абсолютным путем
        for f in files:
            fullname = os.path.join(path_new, f)  #
            print("fullname :" + fullname)
            print(type(fullname))

            self.playlist.addMedia(
                QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fullname)))  # добавляем в список файлы видео (пути к файлам)

            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

    def open_spisok_1(self):
        #  path_new = "D:\\Видео_Инструкции\\Монтаж элементов интерьера электробуса 6282"
        self.playlist.clear()  # очишаем список
        print("очишаем список playlist перед заполнением")
        files = os.listdir(path_1)  # список имен файлов в папке path
        print("files : " + str(files))  # список файлов с абсолютным путем
        for f in files:
            fullname = os.path.join(path_1, f)  #
            print("fullname :" + fullname)
            print(type(fullname))

            self.playlist.addMedia(
                QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fullname)))  
            # добавляем в список файлы видео (пути к файлам)

            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

    def clear_spisok(self):
        self.playlist.clear()  # очишаем список
        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

    def update_duration(self, duration):
        self.timeSlider.setMaximum(duration)
        if duration >= 0:
            self.totalTimeLabel.setText(hhmmss(duration))

    def update_position(self, position):
        if position >= 0:
            self.currentTimeLabel.setText(hhmmss(position))
        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(True)
        self.timeSlider.setValue(position)
        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(False)

    def playlist_selection_changed(self, ix):
        i = ix.indexes()[0].row()
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(i)

    def playlist_position_changed(self, i):
        if i > -1:
            ix = self.model.index(i)
            self.playlistView.setCurrentIndex(ix)

    def toggle_viewer(self, state):  
        if state:  # если state - True
            self.viewer.show()
        else:
            self.viewer.hide()

    def erroralert(self, *args):
        print(args)

    def close_viewer(self):
        print("Закрываем окно просмотра видео (viewer)")
        self.viewer.close()  
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.show_window_1()
        self.hide()
        event.ignore()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setApplicationName("Kiosk Media Player")
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor(25, 25, 25))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipBase, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(45, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.BrightText, Qt.red)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Link, QColor(12, 100, 238))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(12, 115, 228))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.black)
    app.setPalette(palette)
    app.setStyleSheet(
        "QToolTip { color: #ffffff; background-color: #2a82da; border: 1px solid white; }"
    )

    window = MainWindow()
#    window.show()                             # !!! ЭТОГО ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ НАДО
    window.show_window_1()  # показываем окно № 1 Основной раздел
#    print("скроем главное окно")
#    window.hide()  # скроем главное окно       # !!! ЭТОГО ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ НАДО
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**MainWindow.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(845, 496)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../PycharmProjects/Video_Player/NEFAZ ICONS/logo.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(36, 36))
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.playlistView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralWidget)
        self.playlistView.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.playlistView.setProperty("showDropIndicator", True)
        self.playlistView.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)
        self.playlistView.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
        self.playlistView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.playlistView.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.playlistView.setObjectName("playlistView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.playlistView)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.currentTimeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.currentTimeLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        self.currentTimeLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.currentTimeLabel.setObjectName("currentTimeLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.currentTimeLabel)
        self.timeSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralWidget)
        self.timeSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.timeSlider.setObjectName("timeSlider")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.timeSlider)
        self.totalTimeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.totalTimeLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        self.totalTimeLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.totalTimeLabel.setObjectName("totalTimeLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.totalTimeLabel)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.previousButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.previousButton.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../PycharmProjects/Video_Player/images/control-skip-180.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.previousButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.previousButton.setObjectName("previousButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.previousButton)
        self.playButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../PycharmProjects/Video_Player/3706872-control-music-play-play-music-play-sound-start_108717.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.playButton.setIcon(icon2)
        self.playButton.setObjectName("playButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.playButton)
        self.pauseButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../PycharmProjects/Video_Player/images/control-pause.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pauseButton.setIcon(icon3)
        self.pauseButton.setObjectName("pauseButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pauseButton)
        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../PycharmProjects/Video_Player/ico/Stop1NormalYellow_26945.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.stopButton.setIcon(icon4)
        self.stopButton.setObjectName("stopButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.nextButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.nextButton.setText("")
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../PycharmProjects/Video_Player/images/control-skip.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.nextButton.setIcon(icon5)
        self.nextButton.setObjectName("nextButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.nextButton)
        self.viewButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../PycharmProjects/Video_Player/images/application-image.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.viewButton.setIcon(icon6)
        self.viewButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.viewButton.setObjectName("viewButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.viewButton)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../PycharmProjects/Video_Player/images/speaker-volume.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label)
        self.volumeSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralWidget)
        self.volumeSlider.setMaximum(100)
        self.volumeSlider.setProperty("value", 100)
        self.volumeSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volumeSlider.setObjectName("volumeSlider")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.volumeSlider)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 23))
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 16777215))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 845, 25))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        self.menuFIle = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuFIle.setObjectName("menuFIle")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.open_file_action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.open_file_action.setObjectName("open_file_action")
        self.menuFIle.addAction(self.open_file_action)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuFIle.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "PAO \"NEFAZ\""))
        self.currentTimeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0:00"))
        self.totalTimeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0:00"))
        self.playButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PLAY"))
        self.pauseButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PAUSE"))
        self.stopButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "STOP"))
        self.viewButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОТКРЫТЬ ОКНО С ВИДЕО"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вернуться в раздел видеоуроков"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "загрузить список видеофайлов"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОЧИСТИТЬ СПИСОК"))
        self.menuFIle.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "FIle"))
        self.open_file_action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open file..."))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам хороший Человек :) Понял свои ошибки упущения благодаря вашим комментариям в коде ... respect forever !!!